# Changing the header of the response on NodeJS using request

Tags: node.js, express, request

I have the following problem:

I want to get a static file from another server, and give it back to the user with another content-type header.

The following code works just fine, but I can't figure out a way to change the response header, though.

```
const request = require('request');

app.get('video', function (req, res) {
    request.get('http://anotherurl.com/video-sample.mp4').pipe(res);
});
```

I tried to do this thing more manually, but the response was very slow.

```
app.get('video', function (req, res) {
  request.get('http://anotherurl.com/video-sample.mp4', function(error, response, body) {
    // ...
    res.setHeader('content-type', 'image/png');
    res.send(new Buffer(body));
  });
});
```

Can you guys help me with that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the response header when the `'response'` event fires.

```
app.get('video', (req, res) => {
    request.get('http://anotherurl.com/video-sample.mp4')
    .on('response', response => {
      res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'image/png');

      // pipe response to res 
      // since response is an http.IncomingMessage
      response.pipe(res);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I actually tried that earlier, it didn't work though. Apparently this file i'm trying to get has a content-type, that overwrites mine. 

Do you know a work-around this? Maybe some event that fires after the file is fetched? :s

Comment: @ThallesMaia check my updated answer, since the response returned from request is a `http.IncomingMessage` we can just pipe directly from that since all `http.IncomingMessages`s are also `stream.Readable`s.

Comment: you're awesome! It worked like a charm! Thanks, mate!

Comment: @ThallesMaia if this was indeed the answer you should mark it as the answer. StackOverflow relies on the community to identify correct solutions to better help people who may experience this same problem.

Comment: Oh, sorry about that. I'm new to ~being a user on~ StackOverflow