# Sitemap URL not defined in robots.txt Websiteplanet

Tags: reactjs, next.js, seo, sitemap, robots.txt

This is what my `robots.txt` looks like:

```
User-Agent: *
Disallow: /info/privacy
Disallow: /info/cookies
Allow: /
Allow : /search/Jaén
Allow : /search/Tarragona
Allow : /search/Rioja
Sitemap: https://www.alquileres.xyz/sitemap.xml
```

but when I check the sitemap on websiteplanet, it says Sitemap URL not defined in `robots.txt`
Sitemap not return correct `Content-type` header. I checked in Postman, is `application/xml`, I don't know if it has to be another content-type

Also. Isn't redundant to specify other URLs when I insert `Allow: /`? My sitemap eventually is going to be massive, does my robots need to be as well?

I'm working with NextJs

I've tried running both the sitemap and robots in ts files as NextJs offers with its Metadata Object Type. I've also tried inserting the plain files in the app directory

Answer (score 0):

The `Content-Type` for `robots.txt` should be `text/plain`.  Maybe this would be helpful for figuring out how to change it: [Changing the header of the response on NodeJS using request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43354784/changing-the-header-of-the-response-on-nodejs-using-request)

The default assumption that bots make is that everything on your site is crawlable. There is no need to include `Allow` rules unless they disagree with `Disallow` rules.  In fact, in the original `robots.txt` spec, there was no `Allow` directive at all.

Allowing `/search` URLs worries me. If those are site-search results pages, that could be horrible for SEO. Search engines don't like sending users from their search results only to land on other search results. They consider it bad user experience and often penalize sites that allow their search results to be crawled and indexed.  If your `/Search` URLs represent a database query rather than free form text entry to a search results page, I would recommend using some other word in your URL.

You should let your privacy and cookies policies get crawled. Search engines consider sites that have them to be higher quality. If you let them get crawled, they would rarely show up in the search results other than if somebody searches for it specifically like `<your site> privacy policy`.

I'd recommend you use this:

```
User-Agent: *
Disallow: /search
Sitemap: https://www.alquileres.xyz/sitemap.xml
```

Comment: Thanks for the commet! I will delete those search, is just a word in url, i will change to /madrid instead of /search/madrid.  Im new to this so maybe I'm not understanding but what do you mean by site-search results pages? Every route with that city, do a fetch to get results from a database and every single city is present in the sitemap (currently 50)  so there are 50 <url> tags in the sitemap

Comment: Site search would be like `https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&searchOn=1&q=hello%20world` where there is a search index for the site and you can search for whatever you want.